# Как сверстать блок с отверстием с помощью CSS или SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

Интересно было бы увидеть решение на `CSS`, но `SVG` тоже подойдет.
Идеально было бы с адаптивностью.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вариант на `CSS`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: url("http://www.yorkpress.co.uk/resources/images/6599017.jpg?display=1&htype=0&type=responsive-gallery")20% 10%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 2rem;
  width: 20rem;
  height: 20rem;
  background-color: white;
  border: 0.0625rem solid red;
}

.wrapper .angle {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1rem;
  width: calc(50% - 1rem);
}

.angle:first-child {
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 1rem solid white;
  border-right: 1rem solid transparent;
}

.angle:last-child {
  right: 0;
  border-bottom: 1rem solid white;
  border-left: 1rem solid transparent;
}

.angle::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.04rem;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 98.5%;
  transform: scale(1.02)
}

.angle:first-child::before {
  left: 0.0625rem;
  border-bottom: 1rem solid red;
  border-right: 1rem solid transparent;
}

.angle:last-child::before {
  right: 0.0625rem;
  border-bottom: 1rem solid red;
  border-left: 1rem solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="angle"></div>
  <div class="angle"></div>
</div>
```

Вариант на `SVG`:

```css
body {
  background: url("http://www.yorkpress.co.uk/resources/images/6599017.jpg?display=1&htype=0&type=responsive-gallery")20% 10%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="290" height="310" viewBox="0 0 290 310">
  <polygon points="10 10 125 10 150 35 175 10 285 10 285 300 10 300" fill="white" stroke="red"/> 
</svg>
```

Comment: не подходит, доолжно фон быть видно через этот треугольник

Comment: извиняюсь, не проверил. спасибо большое)

Comment: @WVFFLIFE, всегда рад помочь. Если желаете, могу добавить вариант на `SVG`.

Comment: буду благодарен. было бы интересно посмотреть

Comment: @WVFFLIFE, добавил второй вариант. Намного проще реализовать с `SVG`.

Answer (score 5):

Хоть и есть принятый ответ, но я ярый любитель правила один элемент – один тег. И не смог пройти мимо:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(wheat , aquamarine);
}

.pane {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 20px, white 20px);
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 30px 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.pane:before {
  content: '';
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 0 0 -11px;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  background-color: white;
  transform: skewX(45deg);
}

.pane:after {
  content: '';
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 -11px 0 0;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  background-color: white;
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="pane">
  StackOverflow.com
</div>
```

Comment: Честно сказать.. тоже ярый любитель:) `skew` — хорошая идея.